# return "undefined" while consuming the API data in Angular4

Tags: angular

I am trying to consume the API response in my application it always returns "undefined".

This is my service file.

```
get_Image_Path(pName: string){
    this.current_product = pName.trim();
    this.serviceUrl = `http://localhost:abc/api/data/GetImage/?imageName=${this.current_product}`;
    return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl);
  }
```

my-cart.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.get_Image_Path(this.product_Name)
      .subscribe(
        data => { data =>this.check =data
        });
  }
```

HTML code

```
<div *ngFor="let item of check">

  <span>{{item.big_Images}}</span>
  <span>{{item.small_Images}}</span>
  <span>{{item.selected_Product_Image}}</span>
</div>
```

API response structure

[image]

I want to bind all the data from api.

Comment: are you using http or httpclient? @Adam

Comment: @SuvethanNantha,I am using http

Comment: check the answer I posted and let me know if you still have issue

Answer (score 0):

Change you'r ngOnInit() function like below :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.get_Image_Path(this.product_Name)
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => { this.check = data });
  }
```

You also can debug your code to add debugger; inside your service call like below:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.get_Image_Path(this.product_Name)
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          debugger;
          this.check = data 
        });
  }
```

note. when you add debugger inside you'r code you have to keep inspect of your browser be open while running you'r code.

Comment: do you think this will be a solution for the question asked?

Comment: but by using this code I can get the Array of API response in console

Comment: When I refresh the browser window ,Array values are sets to length 0

Comment: @SuvethanNantha I find a wrong coding and I fixed in my solution . Thats all

Comment: @Adam I think this is because of you'r server. after refreshing you'r page will you get data again in you'r network tab ?

Comment: @Arashbahreini, I can't get data in network data after reload,How can I resolve this issue

Comment: @Adam So the problem is from you'r server. I think you should close this issue and open another issue for you'r server. if you wrote your server side with C# then i can help you and you can send you'r new issue link for me :)

Comment: Okay sure @Arashbahreini

Comment: @Adam Please Vote this post up ( if it helps ) and check the answer as solved issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your service code and component code like this. Hope this helps.

```
    get_Image_Path(pName: string){
        this.current_product = pName.trim();
        this.serviceUrl = `http://localhost:abc/api/data/GetImage/?imageName=${this.current_product}`;
            return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl).map((res) => {
    return res.json();
    });
}


ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.get_Image_Path(this.product_Name)
      .subscribe((data) => { this.check = data});
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**service .ts**

```
import {Http,Request,Response,Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";

get_Image_Path(pName: string):Observable<any>{
    this.current_product = pName.trim();
    this.serviceUrl = `http://localhost:abc/api/data/GetImage/?imageName=${this.current_product}`;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl,options);
}
```

**component.ts**

```
this.CartdataService.get_Image_Path(this.product_Name).subscribe(data => {
    this.check = data;
});
```

I hope this helps you. If you still have any issues let me know.

Comment: got this error in return line 

Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'

Comment: return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl);

Comment: @Adam what is the data type you are returning from the api

Comment: I am trying to return as "String"

Comment: you have attached the API response structure image in the question, according to that your backend api returns an json. am i right?

Comment: @Adam have you imported this header? import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Comment: @Adam check the edited answer and see whether you can get it right now

Comment: @Adam did you check?